# cross-browser (tablet) bug with radio buttons

Tags: html, debugging, cross-browser, radio-button, tablet

I asked a similar question already, but I'm still having this problem.

The [website](http://www.izzas-skin-care.com) I made has a bug on tablets. The different content sections don't display properly on tablets - things overlap. The Google Maps iframe, for instance, shows upon page load, not upon clicking on the corresponding radio button (label!). This only happens on tablets.

After some deep thinking, I found that the radio buttons are probably the culprit. On desktops everything looks A-OK.

Sorry, I can't make a JSfiddle to reproduce the tablet issue (help is explicitly sought only from those who can use dev tools, take a quick look and maybe point me to what needs to be done in order to make it work on tablets, in short only from real badass cross-browser Chucknorisses).

Help would be much, much appreciated!

UPDATE:

The radio-buttons I'm talking about are 'design-hidden' to only keep labels as visible / clickable elements.

The code looks like this (this would be the yellow 'home' button):

```
<div class="mx-button" id="real_button5">
                    <input type="radio" name="mx" id="button5" checked>
                    <label for="button5" onclick="" style="background-color: rgba(255,216,0,1);">HOME</label> 
</div>
```

It seems that on tablets, these buttons are clickable (something happens), but they don't unhide the correct content. Things overlap.

Comment: Ok but whats the issue ?

Comment: I can't even spot a radiobutton...

Comment: Ah I added the code part, sorry!

Comment: I hope the UPDATE above describes the issue? If not, the down votes already took my right to add a screen shot away... SO is pretty abrasive.

Comment: I can't figure out why you are using radio buttons for this purpose. They're definitely not meant for this! Just use normal buttons and use javascript to hide all content divs and afterwards show the one you chose...

Comment: It's my first project. I was still experimenting with ways to selectively hide / unhide content areas. The radio button hack seemed like the only way I could do it with pure HTML / CSS. Since I'm not too familiar with JS yet... but I'll try to look into it more, thank you :)

Comment: If you include a little structural help, such as a general example, I'll accept it as an answer though!

Comment: I had some other things to finish first, but here's some code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using jQuery within your project I built a [small example fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fShQ3/1/) for you. Th concept behind it is the following:

All menu buttons have the class `menubutton`. This gives you the possibility to style the buttons but allows you additionally to use a jQuery selector on them. Further I gave each button a `value` attribute. This attribute represents the id of the content div which should be shown.

The content divs also have a common class `content` and an `id` correspondig to the vlaue attributes above.

```
<button class="menubutton" value="content1">item1</button>
<button class="menubutton" value="content2">item2</button>
<button class="menubutton" value="content3">item2</button>

<div class="content" id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="content2">Content 2</div>
<div class="content" id="content3">Content 3</div>
```

Now I use CSS to hide all content divs by default:

```
.content {
    display:none;
}
```

The JavaScript part is also not that complicated. I add a click-function to each element with the class `menubutton`. This is done with a [jQuery selector](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/). Now all content divs are selected by `$(".content")` and I hide them with `hide()`.
`this.value` is the value attribute of the button you clicked on and is used to show this specific content div.

```
$('.menubutton').click( function() {
   $(".content").hide();  
   $("#" + this.value).show();
});
```

I hope this shows you some of the jQuery possibilities.

---

UPDATE

As you want to use divs instead of buttons I made some changes on the example you can see them in this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fShQ3/2/).

I changed from buttons to divs and added an id to each content div like the following:

```
<div class="menubutton" id="content1">item1</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="content2">item2</div>
<div class="menubutton" id="content3">item2</div>

<div class="content" id="show_content1">Content 1</div>
<div class="content" id="show_content2">Content 2</div>
<div class="content" id="show_content3">Content 3</div>
```

the id of content div matches the id of its navigation div plus a standard prefix. `show_` in my example. The JS Code was updated to use the id, instead of the value property to find the desired content div:

```
$('.menubutton').click( function() {
   $(".content").hide();  
   $("#show_" + this.id).show();
});
```

---

UPDATE II

To show one content div by default, you can add another css class to this div (see updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/fShQ3/3/))

```
<div class="content default_content" id="show_content1">Content 1</div>
```

I added this corresponding class to the CSS file:

```
.default_content {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again - it doesn't work yet. I've uploaded the files so the original question's web link is the current version.

I'm suspecting that either the buttons aren't properly 'linked' to the .content areas, or that the third line of JS code doesn't work.

I have moved the closing " after value, so it's:
    $("# + this.value").show(); now,
but it still doesn't work.

Comment: First you should update to a recent version of jQuery - you are still using 1.3.1 while 1.11.1 is available in the meantime. Further my example was based on Buttons. You changed buttons to divs, while divs can't handle the value-tag. I'll post an update to my question to tackle your problem within a few minutes.

Comment: wow! That solved my problem!! Thank you! The only remaining little question is how to make the home button 'clicked' by default (on page load)... I'll google that in the mean time. The broken design in the services section is relatively easy to fix now. And it works on tablets now! I'm indebted to you!

Comment: I updated my fiddle once again for you: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fShQ3/3/ Update to the answer will follow.

Comment: Thank you so much for going out of your way, giving such a detailed and helpful explanation! I'll try to change the question a little bit to make this a useful tutorial for others as well :)